# .NET API and Keycloak

Tags: c#, .net-core, keycloak, openid

I have setup a Keycloak server and front-end, but I can't seem to understand how to set it up on my .NET 5 backend API. I have setup one backend client and one front-end client on Keycloak.
Client-protocol is openid-connect and access type is public in Keycloak on both clients, but I can change that if necessary.

The front-end works find and I can login, and the front-end will send the token on request to the API with header (Authorization) with value "Bearer " + token.

In the controller I have added the Authorize tag:

```
        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetAllRelays()
        {
```

All endpoints with [Authorize] tag returns 401 atm.

And in the Startup.cs I have:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(o =>
            {
                o.Authority = KeycloakServerRealm;
                o.Audience = KeycloakClientId;
                o.MetadataAddress = KeycloakServerRealm + "/.well-known/openid-configuration";
            });
```

KeycloakServerRealm is: "https://dev.my-domain.com/auth/realms/my-realm"

KeycloakMetadata is: "https://dev.my-domain.com/auth/realms/my-realm/.well-known/openid-configuration"

KeycloakClientId is: "my-backend-client-id"

What more do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

The variable KeycloakServerRealm is: "https://dev.my-domain.com/auth/realms/my-realm"

must be : KeycloakServerRealm is: "https://dev.my-domain.com/"
it works for me